# Swashbuckle Swagger - Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, content-security-policy, swashbuckle

I've added a CSP header (using custom middleware) to the response of Web API. Unfortunately, it broke a Swagger UI which is generated by Swashbuckle Nuget v5.6.0. The problem is in generated index.html which contains inline js script which violates CSP.

Is there any way to fix it without changing header values? I would like to stick to the current policy.

I found some opened/closed issues on GitHub project page but I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: You can check the following blog https://mderriey.com/2020/12/14/how-to-lock-down-csp-using-swachbuckle/ (I'm not sure what that blog's licence is, so I'm not copying the content as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is in generated index.html which contains **inline js script** which violates CSP.
> Is there any way to fix it **without changing header** values? I would like to stick to the current policy.

Obviously, there is only one way - to remove all inline scripts into external files.

And you did not show your CSP header, may be it contaits `'nonce-value'` so you can use it to allow some kinds of inline scripts.

Comment: I can't move this script to an external file since there are some tokens that are replaced when HTML file is provided (replacement is done by nuget package). 

There is `nonce-{random}` in my header but I can't append it to the script itself since library does not provide any option to do it :(

Comment: You can use `'hash-value'` to allow inline scripts